# Как вывести имя в компоненте?

Tags: vue.js

```js
Vue.component('helloworld', {
  template: '#helloworld',
   data: ()=> ({
    name: 'helloworld'
  })
 
})

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<template id="helloworld">
  {{name}}
</template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Comment: Подскажите, от куда берётся компонент `App` и что находится в нём?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на строчку createApp(App).mount('#app'), она означает, что ваше приложение собирается внутри тега с аттрибутом id="app", нужно просто перенести вывод имени внутрь этого тега